# SiberianCMS installation Fatal Error "String could not be parsed as XML"

Tags: php, zend-framework, siberiancms

While installing siberianCMS SAE version on my windows 10 os with wamp64 version getting below error.

```
 [exception] => Exception Object
                (
                    [message:protected] => String could not be parsed as XML
                    [string:Exception:private] => 
                    [code:protected] => 0
                    [file:protected] => F:\wamp64\www\sbcms\lib\Siberian\Layout.php
                    [line:protected] => 541
```

This look like the installation script does not providing the /layout/front.xml
file.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have Cygwin installed? From the [Requirements page](https://developers.siberiancms.com/documentation/#requirements): "_Recommended Server OS: Linux - For local development only: Works on OSX with homebrew, and on Windows with cygwin_"

Comment: @kerbholz yes, Now I am checking with linux system.
Does anyone done with module development in siberianCMS for a totally new editor?